# Android geocoding not functioning as well as iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, google-maps, geocoding

So I have a function for converting an address (String) into coordinates.

This is what it looks like in iOS:

```
func setCoords(buildet: BuildingDetail) {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(buildet.address, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {
                println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                let location = placemark.location
                buildet.lat = location.coordinate.latitude
                buildet.lon = location.coordinate.longitude
            }
            self.setupMarker(buildet)
    })
}
```

This is what it looks like in Android:

```
public static double[] getLatLongPositions(String address) throws Exception
{
    int responseCode = 0;
    String api = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=true";
    System.out.println("URL : "+api);
    URL url = new URL(api);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpConnection.connect();
    responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == 200)
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();;
        Document document = builder.parse(httpConnection.getInputStream());
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/status");
        String status = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
        if(status.equals("OK"))
        {
            expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat");
            String latitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
            expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lng");
            String longitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
            return new double[] {Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)};
        }
    }
    return new double[]{0,0};
}
```

Now, the iOS function above just runs the setupMarker function, where the Android method returns the coordinates, no big deal!

The problem I have is, I am supplying both functions with the exact same address arguments.

iOS returns all the coordinates perfectly.

Whereas, Android only returns around 30% of them properly.

Is there an Android function equivalent to the iOS one above, or just one that can geocode properly.

As you can see the Android calls the API here:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=
```

And I have tested this, it doesn't give good results, at least not as good as iOS.

What can I do about it?

**EDIT - Some Examples** (All work with iOS)

- EBS, 2 Burlington Road, Dublin 2
- AIB Bankcentre, Merrion Road, Ballsbridge, Dublin 4, Ireland
- AIB, Unit 33, Sandyford Business Centre, Sandyford, Dublin 18

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of the addresses that are failing on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a URL that returns data in JSON format, which you can then parse and get the latitude and longitude. Here is an example:

```
public static void getLatLongFromAddress(String youraddress) {
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
              youraddress + "&sensor=false";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    int b;
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

    double lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
        .getDouble("lng");

    double lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
        .getDouble("lat");

    Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
    Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you try it with the examples OP provided it still returns no results. It's not an issue of the formatting of the results, the API simply can't find the address.

Comment: It does work, there is nothing wrong with the API. Here the result in json format [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2+Burlington%20Road,+Dublin+2&sensor=false). In xml [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=2+Burlington%20Road,+Dublin+2). What could be the problem  is the way the address is appended to the URL.

Comment: That's not the entire address as given by OP. The "EBS" at the beginning throws it off

Comment: Okay, so i think the problem here the URL. The OP is using maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/ and I was trying with http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/. My  JSON format [link] (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=EBS,%202%20Burlington%20Road,%20Dublin&sensor=false). XML formal [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=EBS,%202%20Burlington%20Road,%20Dublin). OP I suggest you change the URL to the one I mentioned and see if that gives you results.

Comment: I have tried your method, and it yields identical results. It must be the same data, just different format.

Comment: The error is because google maps API doesn't accept the number value that follows after Dublin. If you test it out it works when you put that value infront of Dublin.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Why is this not the case with iOS?

Comment: It is most likely due to the way we in define addresses in North America, the country/city/address always follows after the number. Its reading the 2 at the end and appending, %202, to the end of the URL which throw an error. Also there could be a work around like specifying a region or component country. See link below on region biasing for more information. Well, iOS isn't using the google maps geocoder, its using its geocoder in its core location framework which is independent of the way android does it.  
[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes)